# Yahoo historic intraday stock data via YQL (just like chart api)?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I know I can get historical intraday data (up 15 days) using chart api as follows

```
http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/xml/
```

Using YQL, and

```
env 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
```

I can use .quotes and .historicaldata:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT") and startDate = "2012-09-13" and endDate = "2012-09-13"
```

What I can't figure out is how to use a YQL statement to obtain historical intraday data (like using chartapi; probably limited to a few days in range).

Is there any documentation about this somewhere?

Alex